# Create a new nested list / tuple based on the given data in the table [Python]

Tags: python

Is it possible to create a new list / tuple base on this sample table

```
 ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
|   i_id   |   desc   |   c_id   |   p_id   |    qty   |
 ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
|   PIZ    |  Pizza   |    1     |     0    |     1    |
 ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
|   OLV    |  Olive   |    2     |     1    |     1    |
 ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
|   MUS    | Mushroom |    3     |     1    |     1    |
 ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
|   BUR    |  Burger  |    4     |     0    |     1    |
 ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
|   PIC    |  Pickles |    5     |     4    |     1    |
 ---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
```

To get the data from the above table, I ran a `SELECT` query.

```
import pymysql

class GetData:

    def __init__(self):
        database_connection setup
        ...

    def get_data(self):
        self.test_list = []
        self.cur.execute("SELECT * FROM tblmenu;")
        result = self.cur.fetchall()
        for item in result:
            self.test_list.append([item[0],item[1],item[4]])
        return self.test_list

...
```

If `p_id` is equal to `c_id` then it is a child item of that `c_id`.

Expected list/tuple is:

```
[('PIZ', 'Pizza', 1), ('CON', 'Olive, Mushroom', 2), ('BUR', 'Burger', 1), ('CON', 'Pickles', 1)]
```

**Breakdown of the expected list/tuple**

1. [(i_id, desc, qty)]
2. In the list, the child items will be consolidated into 1 item. An example is the Olive and Mushroom, it also needs to sum it's `qty`.
3. Child item/s will have `CON` as `i_id` or index[0].

TIA for your help.

EDIT: Added some script

Comment: Hi! Could you provide what you have done so far?

Comment: Hi @BastienAntoine, I added a Python script to get the data from MySQL, I also added a function to create the list but without the conditions I added in the expected list/tuple. I'm not sure how to consolidate the items into one item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like that:

```
data = [
    {'i_id': 'PIZ', 'desc': 'Pizza', 'c_id': 1, 'p_id': 0, 'qty': 1},
    {'i_id': 'OLV', 'desc': 'Olive', 'c_id': 2, 'p_id': 1, 'qty': 1},
    {'i_id': 'MUS', 'desc': 'Mushroom', 'c_id': 3, 'p_id': 1, 'qty': 1},
    {'i_id': 'BUR', 'desc': 'Burger', 'c_id': 4, 'p_id': 0, 'qty': 1},
    {'i_id': 'PIC', 'desc': 'Pickles', 'c_id': 5, 'p_id': 4, 'qty': 1},
]

p_list = [ p for p in data if p['p_id']==0 ]
c_desc_list = [ ', '.join([c['desc'] for c in data if c['p_id'] == p['c_id'] ]) for p in p_list ]
c_qty_list = [ sum([c['qty'] for c in data if c['p_id'] == p['c_id'] ]) for p in p_list ]

result = []
for i in range(len(p_list)):
    result.append((p_list[i]['i_id'], p_list[i]['desc'], p_list[i]['qty']))
    result.append(('CON', c_desc_list[i], c_qty_list[i]))

print(result)
# output: [('PIZ', 'Pizza', 1), ('CON', 'Olive, Mushroom', 2), ('BUR', 'Burger', 1), ('CON', 'Pickles', 1)]
```